# how to set the outer <div> adapt to the browser,and the div in it adapt to the outer one?

Tags: html, css, browser

first here is my html demo code

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>                                 
    </div>
```

I set the outer `<div class="wrapper">` adapt to the browser with the css attribute  **"height:100%;"**,

as well set the **"overflow:hidden;"** in order to set  the `<div class="item"></div>` could adapt to outer one.

When the browser height reduced or folded,the brower nust not appear the scroll bar,the scroll could always display in the `<div class="wrapper">`

but it could not be achieved,[Here is my case](http://jsfiddle.net/hh54188/6WGe2/)

how to solved the problem?

thank you:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be something like this http://jsfiddle.net/g536q/?

Answer (score 0):

Please change

```
overflow:hidden;
```

to

```
overflow:auto;
```